# Is my understanding correct for the first rule of the makefile?

Tags: makefile

I'm learning **make**, and try to understand the following makefile from [Prerequisite-Types](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Prerequisite-Types.html#Prerequisite-Types)

```
OBJDIR := objdir
OBJS := $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/,foo.o bar.o baz.o)

$(OBJDIR)/%.o : %.c
        $(COMPILE.c) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<

all: $(OBJS)

$(OBJS): | $(OBJDIR)

$(OBJDIR):
        mkdir $(OBJDIR)
```

The first rule confuses me. It's to be firstly applied. Since `$(OBJDIR)` is not there, the last rule will be applied to mkdir objdir. Then, since there's nothing in the newly created directory, there's no *stem*.o, and correspondingly, no *stem*.c So the prerequisites and recipes seem to be meaningless.

The only thing that the first rule does is to make a directory, which seems to be unreal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The first rule is a [pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Rules), so it cannot be the default rule; it will not be the first applied unless you specify e.g. `make thing.o`.
2. The first rule might not do what you expect. The recipe is `$(COMPILE.c) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<`, but you don't assign a value to `OUTPUT_OPTION` in the makefile; unless you provide a value from outside (e.g. `make thing.o OPTION_OUTPUT=...`) this recipe has no special instructions about where to put the file it builds, it has never heard of `objdir/`, and will use the compiler's default which is probably the working directory.
3. The last rule will build `objdir` (if `objdir` does not already exist, and if Make invokes that rule). The command `make objdir` will work perfectly. If you try to build one of the object files listed in `OBJS`, Make will construct the directory (if the directory does not exit) -- not because it needs a place to put the file, but because `$(OBJDIR)` is a prerequisite of every member of `$(OBJS)`, according to the third rule. It will *not* construct the directory if you try to build `objdir/thing.o`, because `$(OBJDIR)` is not a prerequisite of that target. You think Make should build it because it is obviously needed? Well, Make isn't that smart.
4. The first rule has a prerequisite pattern `%.c`, and the recipe looks for the source file in the working directory, *not* in any newly constructed subdirectory. If there is no such source file in the working directory, Make will not run that rule.

Comment: Thanks! Very comprehensive. The idiom `default rule` you used inspired me to find out that there are two exceptions for `The default goal is the target of the first rule in the first makefile.`

Answer (score 0):

I don't really follow your logic.

The first rule in your makefile is this:

```
all: $(OBJS)
```

so the default goal for this makefile (if you don't specify one on the command line) is `all`.

`all` depends on all the `.o` files.  All the `.o` files have an order-only dependency on the directory.  So, first the directory is created, then the `.o` files are created, then `all` is done (there is no recipe here to create a program or library or anything out of those `.o` files).